# Methods of Deleting Duplicates in SQL Server with SSDT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, duplicates, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently setting up a database which has an upload process in SSDT. It pulls data over time from an Excel sheet. My issue is that the Excel sheet is appended onto as time continues but the upload process uploads the entire sheet every time the process is run. This results in exact, duplicate rows for the data which were in there previously.

I have attempted to solve this in a number of ways. I have attempted to use the Sort function included in SSDT but have not been able to get it to work for whatever reason. I am considering writing and SQL task to clean the database after each upload but am only so confident in my ability to do so. Is there some method I am not thinking of which would make this easier or a way to get the sort transformation to work? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Cleanup your dupes programmatically after or staging table -> perm table and don't merge the dupes.

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that you have to have a little over double the amount of space in the database to create the temporary table before the merge, although I do not think any of the other suggestions have figured out a way around this yet. Perhaps I will try this.

Comment: Could purge the table before loading, but if load fails you're gonna be without the data as you just purged it. Safer loading the data and manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete duplicate rows in SQL Server using a cte with row_number() window function.

Comment: This was the SQL task to execute I was thinking of writing. It seems like it might be the better way to go. Will attempt it later today.